variable points for questions from question bank using exam documentclass
I would like to create question bank in Overleaf from which lecturers can draw questions to put into their exams but still be able to easily adjust the points awarded for each question within the exam documentclass framework. My current plan is this:
Create the question bank as a folder, in which each question is a separate .tex file. This will later be parsed into a catalogue including the .tex filenames, so that lecturers only need to note the filename of the questions they like to use (e.g. "exercise1.tex").
Create a exam documentclass template for them to use, with a command to insert questions and adjust the awarded points like this
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\NewDocumentCommand\singlequestion{mm}{\question[#2] \input{#1}}
\singlequestion{exercise1.tex}{3}

This adds the question from exercise1.tex to the exam with a worth of 3 points.
The problem is that the exam class also has multipart questions with the syntax
\question
Question text.
\begin{parts}
    \part[X] First part of the question, awarding X points.
    \part[Y] Second part of the question, awarding Y points.
\end{parts}

This is not as straight forward as the simple command above. I would need a new command that takes the .tex file, in which the multipart question is written, as its first argument, and then further arguments specifying how many points are awarded for each partial question. The command would then need to replace the \part[X] with the actual points defined in the arguments. Ideally, the number of arguments should be variable, so you can use the same command, no matter how many partial questions a multipart question has.
I tried the solution from How to replace text, but this does not play well with the \input command (i.e., it tries to replace the text before the actual contents from the .tex file are added).

Welcome to TeX.SX! How would a document containing a single question look like? You can maybe locally redefine things or you can first input and then replace.

Thanks for the input! I just realized that I am essentially trying to pass parameter to the input, which I managed to solve similar to this

Ok, let's close as a duplicate then.
